# cte in recursive member of rcte

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a rcte that has a cte in its recursive member. Notice the 'inner' cte (named cte_o) being referenced twice in the recursive member of the outer cte. This code does not parse in SQL Server 2017. Is there a way to do this ?

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (xIdOf int,xIdLot int,xCoeff float);

    SELECT
        @pIdOf
        ,s.LOE_IdLot
        ,s.LOE_PdsS/(SELECT SUM(s1.LOE_PdsS) FROM dbo.REF_LOTS_STOCKOUT_OF AS s1 WHERE s1.LOE_IdOF=@pIdOf)
    FROM REF_LOTS_STOCKOUT_OF AS s
    WHERE s.LOE_IdOF=@pIdOf

    UNION ALL

    WITH cte_o(oIdOf, oIdLot, oPds, oCoeff) AS (
        SELECT s.LOE_IdOF,s.LOE_IdLot,AVG(s.LOE_PdsS),SUM(x.xCoeff)
        FROM
            @x As x
            INNER JOIN REF_LOTS_STOCKIN_OF AS e
                ON x.xIdLot=e.LOS_IdLot
            INNER JOIN REF_LOTS_STOCKOUT_OF AS s
                ON e.LOS_IdOF=s.LOE_IdOF
        GROUP BY s.LOE_IdOF,s.LOE_IdLot
    )
    SELECT
        o.oIdOf
        ,o.oIdLot
        ,o.oPds/(SELECT SUM(oS.oPds) FROM cte_o AS oS WHERE oS.oIdOf=o.oIdOf)*o.oCoeff
    FROM cte_o AS o;
```

Hereafter, the legacy code that I am trying to simplify using rcte instead of loop:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (xIdOf int,xIdLot int,xCoeff float);
DECLARE @o TABLE (oIdOf int,oIdLot int,oPds float,oCoeff float);

INSERT INTO @x
    SELECT
        @pIdOf
        ,s.LOE_IdLot
        ,s.LOE_PdsS/(SELECT SUM(s1.LOE_PdsS) FROM dbo.REF_LOTS_STOCKOUT_OF AS s1 WHERE s1.LOE_IdOF=@pIdOf)
    FROM REF_LOTS_STOCKOUT_OF AS s
    WHERE s.LOE_IdOF=@pIdOf;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT x.xIdLot FROM @x As x)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @retGrapheOf
        SELECT
            @pIdOf
            ,x.xIdLot
            ,b.LBE_IdBE
            ,b.LBE_LgnBE
            ,x.xCoeff
    FROM 
        @x AS x
        INNER JOIN REF_LOTS_STOCKIN_BE AS b
            ON x.xIdLot=b.LBE_IdLot;
    INSERT INTO @o
        SELECT s.LOE_IdOF,s.LOE_IdLot,AVG(s.LOE_PdsS),SUM(x.xCoeff)
        FROM
            @x As x
            INNER JOIN REF_LOTS_STOCKIN_OF AS e
                ON x.xIdLot=e.LOS_IdLot
            INNER JOIN REF_LOTS_STOCKOUT_OF AS s
                ON e.LOS_IdOF=s.LOE_IdOF
        GROUP BY s.LOE_IdOF,s.LOE_IdLot;

    DELETE FROM @x;
    INSERT INTO @x
        SELECT
            o.oIdOf
            ,o.oIdLot
            ,o.oPds/(SELECT SUM(oS.oPds) FROM @o AS oS WHERE oS.oIdOf=o.oIdOf)*o.oCoeff
        FROM @o AS o;
    DELETE FROM @o;
END
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a cte inside the body of the recursion? What are you actually trying to solve here? Please post table definitions and sample data along with desired output so others understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . SQL Server doesn't support CTEs within CTEs, so if that were really needed, you could not do it with a single query in SQL Server.  However, you probably can do what you want.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement would help.

Comment: Because I have a legacy code that uses o loop inside of a rcte. At each iteration in the loop, from @xN @o is created, which in turn serves to build @x(N+1). So I wanted to turn @o into an inner cte, called by an outer rcte

Comment: Still....need table definitions and sample data. Great that you want to turn a loop into a set based but we need some details to help.

Comment: What's wrong with the "legacy" code?  Is it broken?  Is it using something that is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but the query you wrote that doesn't parse would parse if you did it like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (...)
SELECT {queryA}
UNION ALL 
SELECT {queryB} FROM CTE
```

Comment: CTE is a SELECT on the recursive member. So this won't work unfortunately.

Comment: Well, no, it isn't.  Your question mentions an "inner" CTE and an "outer" one, but your code actually only has one CTE, and there is no actual recursion in your code, but I guess you think there is because there's a UNION?   I don't know.   That's why I say it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.   Sample data and desired results might help.

Comment: Explanations about the second code (so called legacy). I find it complex to understand, so I thought about using a rcte. Basically, retGrapheOf is the output table, x is filled in inside a loop. At each iteration, from x(N), @o is built, And then from o, x(N+1) is built. The way x(N+1) is built from o involves referencing it twice (hence the idea of an inner cte. retGraphOf accumulates the values from x across iterations, whereas x only stores values of current iteration.

Comment: Yes, well, the way you are thinking of doing this, your "approach" basically, will not work.  And I can't suggest an alternate approach because you haven't shown us the problem you are trying to solve, other than to show the legacy code.   You have only shown us the solution you are trying to implement, which is hopelessly broken.   Best thing to do to get help is to step back, post a question saying, "I have these tables with this sample data, and I need to process/query them in such a way that I get this result."   Get out of the rut of the way you are trying to do it.